# how to merge a multiIndex dataframe with a singleIndex dataframe, and keep the resulting dataframe multiIndexed

Tags: python, pandas, merge

how to merge a multiIndex dataframe with a singleIndex dataframe, and keep the resulting dataframe multiIndexed

so i have dfA and dfB
dfA:

```
fir    A      B    C
sec    Aa Ab  Ba   Ca  Cb
ind
1      1  2   2    2   1
2      1  2   2    2   1
4      1  2   2    2   1
```

dfB

```
ind
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want the result to be multiIndexed like:

```
fir    A      B    C
sec    Aa Ab  Ba   Ca  Cb
ind
1      1  2   2    2   1
2      1  2   2    2   1
3      0  0   0    0   0
4      1  2   2    2   1
5      0  0   0    0   0
```

I did a simple merge

```
dfA = pd.merge(dfB,dfA,how='left',on='ind').fillna(0)
```

I would have the result dfA as:

```
   ind (A,Aa)(A,Ab)(B,Ba)(C,Ca)(C,Cb)
0   1    2     2     2     2     1
1   2    2     2     2     2     1
2   3    0     0     0     0     0
3   4    2     2     2     2     1
4   5    0     0     0     0     0
```

the columns got flatten,i want to keep them multiIndexed

Answer (score 1):

Just [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `dfA` on `axis=0`:

```
dfA.reindex(dfB['ind'], fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
fir  A     B  C   
sec Aa Ab Ba Ca Cb
ind               
1    1  2  2  2  1
2    1  2  2  2  1
3    0  0  0  0  0
4    1  2  2  2  1
5    0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! "reindex()" did work the way I need it, however the "fill_value=0" didnt work somehow, but i use ".fillna(0)" to solve it anyway. Thanks heaps!!!!